# Python “pip install ” is failing with AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_vendor'

Tags: python, pip

I'm attempting to install a package from a local directory, on Windows Server 2008. The package doesn't really matter I guess, but for arguments sake its Luigi.  I navigate to the directory and use the following command:

```
pip install setup.py
```

and the following error is returned:

```
'module' object has no attribute '_vendor'); 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed.
```

[image: Full error image here]

I've tried to reinstall pip, upgrade pip and install via easy_install and I'm just getting exactly the same error every time.  anyone else had this same error and can recommend a solution?

I've tried;

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
easy_install -U pip
```

I've also tried uninstalling pip but I just get the same error.

Comment: What is the exact command that led you to that error? Can you share the full error stack trace?

Comment: Have you tried `pip3...` instead of `pip`?

Comment: @OferSadan I've elaborated a bit, does this help?

Comment: @marcuse yep, tried that, no difference.

Comment: what does `pip -V` show?

Comment: you say you get the error from `pip install setup.py` but you share the error for the command `pip3 install --upgrade pip`

Comment: What happens if you try `python -m pip install -U pip`?

Answer (score 1):

To install a package from a local directory with pip, you'll use either

```
pip install .
```

or

```
pip install -e .
```

from the directory containing the package's `setup.py`.

Note the `.` at the end.

The `-e` version installs it the same way as `python setup.py develop`